# Open Python file with IDLE using Terminal on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: command-line, python, idle-python

How can I open python file (from desktop) with IDLE, using Terminal on Ubuntu 12.04?

I have tried to do this way:

```
$ idle open python_file.py
```

Instead of open my file it's create two more files: `open` and  `python_file.py`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's just

```
idle python_file.py
```

If you want it to run in the background (returning control to the terminal so you can type other commands), add '&'

```
idle python_file.py &
```

If you want it to continue running even if you close the terminal you can 'disown' it

```
idle python_file.py & disown
```

Answer (score 5):

**You do not need to use the 'open' term.**
The help says:

```
idle.py [-c command] [-d] [-e] [-s] [-t title] [arg] ...

-c command  run this command
-d          enable debugger
-e          edit mode; arguments are files to be edited
-s          run $IDLESTARTUP or $PYTHONSTARTUP first
-t title    set title of shell window
```

You can just do this:

```
idle file_you_want_to_open.py 
or 
idle.py file_you_want_to_open.py
```

If the file doesn't exist then it will be created.

Answer (score 2):

You can also directly open idle by typing :

```
 idle
```

in the terminal and then click on

```
 File >> New File or Open File
```

option to select or open your file , write your program and execute it . However I would recommend you to use the  "***terminal***"  and a  "***text editor***" like

```
 Sublime Text
```

rather than using "***idle***" .

PS: You might already know about these text editors , however I mentioned it in case somebody else new views this article and maybe it comes in handy .

Answer (score 1):

First you have to install idle

```
sudo apt install idle
```

then just type

```
idle
```

and it should open

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
$ cd ~/Desktop
$ idle your_file.py
```

Comment: This does not include the steps on how to open a specific file. I guess some step is missing here?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get your command prompt back after executing `idle` you could use:

```
nohup idle /some/path/to/file.py &
```

or if the file is in your current directory:

```
$ ls
file.py
$ nohup idle file.py &
```

Of course the last one will work if you are in the current directory, if the file do not exist IDLE will create one.

Answer (score 0):

To install and use latest idle,

Go to synaptic package manager and install idle-python3.2

Then go to terminal and just type

`idle-python3.2`

This will open idle-python3.2.

Installation location => *idle-python3.2 in SPM->(select)->idle-python3.2->(right-click)->properties->Installed Files.*

Comment: That tells us how to *install* Idle; it doesn't answer the OP's question, which was how to open a file once Idle is installed.